# Ear clipping triangulation snip calculation

Tags: 3d, triangulation

I have a working code of 2D triangulation of a polygon. This uses the following code to detect if a triangle is actually an ear:

```
private bool Snip (int u, int v, int w, int n, int[] V) 
{
    var A = m_points[V[u]];
    var B = m_points[V[v]];
    var C = m_points[V[w]];

    if (Mathf.Epsilon > (((B.x - A.x) * (C.y - A.y)) - ((B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x))))
        return false;

    for (var p = 0; p < n; p++) 
    {
        if ((p == u) || (p == v) || (p == w))
            continue;

        var P = m_points[V[p]];

        if (InsideTriangle(A, B, C, P))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now I'd wish to make this a 3D function, since I have to rotate all polygons according to their normal into 2D space. The one confusing part is that I do not understand what this code does:

```
if (Mathf.Epsilon > (((B.x - A.x) * (C.y - A.y)) - ((B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x))))
```

Thus making it impossible for me to create a 3D variant on it.

Does anyone know what this does?

Answer (score 1):

The expression on the right-hand side of the inequality is computing the determinant of

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        B.x-A.x&B.y-A.y \\
        C.x-A.x&C.y-A.y \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$
which is twice the (oriented) area of the triangle $ABC$.  So the expression determines if the triangle's area is very small (less than Mathf.Epsilon), *or* if the triangle's vertices are in clockwise order.  I suspect the latter is a bug, and the intention was to was to check the area; in that case, the absolute value should be taken before comparing.

For three dimensions, you would presumably want to compute the corresponding determinant
for the volume, using the matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        B.x-A.x&B.y-A.y&B.z-A.z \\
        C.x-A.x&C.y-A.y&C.z-A.z \\
        D.x-A.x&D.y-A.y&D.z-A.z
        \end{bmatrix},
$$
or the 4x4 matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A.x & A.y & A.z & 1\\
B.x & B.y & B.z & 1\\
C.x & C.y & C.z & 1\\
D.x & D.y & D.z & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My math (unfortunately) is not as wide spread as I wished for. Is this (found it in slimmath) what you mean?

[link](https://code.google.com/p/slimmath/source/browse/trunk/SlimMath/Matrix.cs) line 312

Comment: @Slaaitjuh Not quite; that package works with 4x4 matrices, not 3x3.  But the determinant for volume can also be written as a 4x4 matrix; I'll put it in my answer.